# Python AAD (Azure Active Directory) Authentication with certificate

Tags: python-3.x, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-active-directory, x509certificate

I'm trying to get an access token by authenticating my app with AAD via a certificate. The certificate is installed on my local machine (windows 10). This authentication is needed to access an external API.

I'm following the steps posted on [Azure Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/)

**Sample code:**

```
def authenticate_client_cert():
    """
    Authenticate using service principal w/ cert.
    """
    authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
    tenant = '<TENANT>'
    authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant
    resource_uri = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
    client_id = '<CLIENT_ID>'
    client_cert = '<CLIENT_CERT>' ### MISSING THIS
    client_cert_thumbprint = '<CLIENT_CERT_THUMBPRINT>'

    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri, api_version=None)

    mgmt_token = context.acquire_token_with_client_certificate(resource_uri, client_id, client_cert, client_cert_thumbprint)
    credentials = AADTokenCredentials(mgmt_token, client_id)

    return credentials
```

I have `'<CLIENT_ID>'`, `'<TENANT>'` and `'<CLIENT_CERT_THUMBPRINT>'`
 but I'm missing `'<CLIENT_CERT>'`

From my understanding, `'<CLIENT_CERT>'` is the private key but I cannot export the private key because it's not allowed.

So I'm not sure how I can get authenticated from AAD with this certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot get the private key, you won't use this cert to get authenticated with AAD. But You can upload a new cert by yourself and use it.

The `<client_cert>` should be the **Name of the key file** which you generated.

Here is a documentation about [**Client credentials with certificate in ADAL for python**](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Client-credentials#client-credentials-with-certificate):

> Steps to generate certificate and private key to be used when
>   implementing the client credential flow are as follows:
>
> Generate a key:
>
> `openssl genrsa -out server.pem 2048`
>
> Create a certificate request:
>
> `openssl req -new -key server.pem -out server.csr`
>
> Generate a certificate:
>
> `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.pem -out
>   server.crt`
>
> You will have to upload this certificate (`server.crt`) on Azure
>   Portal in your application settings. Once you save this certificate,
>   the portal will give you the thumbprint of this certificate which is
>   needed in the acquire token call. The key will be the `server.pem` key
>   you generated in the first step.
>
> Now you can create the credential for the client credential flow using
>   certificate in ADAL Python as follows:
>
> ```
> client_credentials = {
>     "client_id": <your app id>,
>     "thumbprint": <thumbprint of cert file>,
>     "certificate": <key file name> 
>  }
> ```

**For example:**

```
 {
   "resource": "your_resource",
   "tenant" : "test.onmicrosoft.com",
   "authorityHostUrl" : "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
   "clientId" : "d6835713-b745-48d1-bb62-7a8248477d35",
   "thumbprint" : 'C15DEA8656ADDF67BE8031D85EBDDC5AD6C436E1',
   "certificate" : 'server.pem'
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my question. The certificate is needed to access an external API (I don't own it). Therefore I cannot create my own certificate to get authenticated. In C#, there's a way to point to a certificate that's installed on your computer but I can't seem to find a library in python that would allow me to that.

Comment: Hi @Rana . Unfortunately, AFAIK, if you cannot export private key neither use a new certificate, I think there is no other workaround to resolve this.